# Как изменить структуру заголовка в head wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как кастомизировать  заголовок в `head` wordpress? Мне нужно создать динамические заголовки для некоторых страниц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, проблема решена))

```
function meteors_home_title(){
    $pages = [62,63,78,92,120];
    foreach ($pages as $page){
        if (get_the_ID() == $page){
            return 'my title';
        }   
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'meteors_home_title' );
```

Comment: не забудьте отметить Ваш ответ решением(зеленая галка под цифрой слева от ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Нужно модифицировать файл header.php вашей темы. Для определения идентификатора текущей страницы следует использовать функцию get_the_ID() и предпринять нужные действия в зависимости от ее результата.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать фильтр `pre_get_document_title`. Так можно задать кастомный `title` страницы.
[Пример](http://www.wp-fan.ru/filtry-i-sobytiya-v-wordpress-kak-i-zachem-ih-ispolzovat/).

Comment: Так можно изменить только заголовок (title) страницы. Вопрос же, как я понимаю, о том, как изменить шапку (head).

Comment: Нет, клиент хочет чтобы тайтл менялся только для поисковиков. Он будет в админке задавать некоторым страницам  другой заголовок.